# Where to place in game object definitions?

Tags: c++, object

This may sound like a stupid question, but I'm not sure how else to do this.

In my c++ ASCII-based roguelike, I will have lots and lots of Objects.  Each allocated, in-game, object will have some properties in common.  (Name, Size, ObjectID, Appearance, Etc.)  Normally, I would use static variables for this, but that would require creating a new class and initializer for each and every Object.  Instead, I've decided have each allocated object contain a pointer to a given ObjectDef, which I can then use to get around this.  I will create a new class for a given **type** of object, when the object has new functionality that needs to be implemented.

That said, **where do I define all of these object definitions**?  I'd like to have them in arrays, but I know global variables are bad, bad, bad.

Some general tips would be great.  Thanks.

```
class WorldObjectDef //WHAT WE HAVE A LIST OF
{
  protected:

    std::string m_name;
    float m_size;

    int m_type;
    int m_id;
    AsciiNode m_node;

  public:

    WorldObjectDef(std::string, float, int, int, const AsciiNode &);

    int getId() const;
    std::string getName() const;
    float getSize() const;
    AsciiNode getNode() const;
};

class WorldObject //WHAT'S ALLOCATED IN A LEVEL
{
    WorldObjectDef * m_def;

  public:

    WorldObject(const WorldObjectDef &);

    int getId() const;
    std::string getName() const;
    float getSize() const;
    AsciiNode getNode() const;
};
```

Something I've been wondering:  Is there anything wrong with html-like code tags?  God it's annoying to space indent every line.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive? Post some code?

Comment: I generally make a `Game` object that holds "globals".

Comment: @MooingDuck I might just do that.  Would a namespace be more fit for this purpose?

Comment: If you have a large block of code, you can highlight it and click the `{}` button to indent all of it magically.

Comment: @thedaian Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I often create List<> that holds all the active objects ( ie. objects that are ingame and in use), that can be used to manipulate all the data in one loop.
That list could be defined anywhere, where its visibility is high enought. If it needs to be global, then so be it. Better to get the code working, than think if its running at max fps.

Dont use globals and gotos are the first warnings i remember to read about. Im not saying you should ignore those warnings, but to understand why its not good practice to use em in large scale.

Globals are bad, becouse they stay live until program exist, or manually disposed. If you have main loop, witch i think you have, you should define those variables in it.

Comment: Where then do I define the list?  I'm trying to keep the object properties separate from the allocated objects themselves.

Comment: @roadkillguy: that makes no sense.  An object is a container of properties..  If you aren't keeping the objects data with itself, then why are you using OOP to begin with?

Comment: Well, they're things that shouldn't change between each instance of a given item, and at the same shouldn't be static because I don't want to create a new class for every in game object.

The name of an object, its size, id, appearance, etc.  Things like that won't change on the allocated objects, but will be used to tell them apart.

Comment: That really sounds like you are still missing the main idea behind the objects and classes. If you have one class, to define all objects in game, then you should create instance of that class for each different type of object with different attributes.

Comment: Idea of OOP is to define object that can be in many forms but it still is the same in the end. Like humans. That could be class. From that, you should define 7Billion instances, to recreate world population and to create all the differenct kinds of human.

Comment: Typing out a new class for every different kind of object is tedious.  My plan is to create a new derived class for different functionality in an object type, not for each and every object.  The point in an ObjectDef is to effectively have some common fields without using static fields.  If I used static, I'd have to create a new derived class for each and every object.  I understand OOP.  I promise.

Comment: I understand globals are bad from a modularity perspective more than any performance issue. If you have a global list of definitions you can still allocate/free the elements when needed - but the problem comes from code maintainance & clarity. Local values passed between modules as arguments show you scope, access,dependancy more clearly, and encourage you to write modular reusable code, easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: @roadkillguy: It just dawned on me that `WorldObjectDef` has the info for "wrenches", and `WorldObject` is an instance of a wrench, and then you only need a tiny number of classes. I got it now.  You need to clarify this in the question.  I think many people are misunderstanding in the same way I was.

Answer (score 1):

I really think there's a problem here.

You don't necessarily need a new class definition for each object type in your game world (Chair, Table, Pencil); but you should have a class definition for each category of object based on the type of behavior that object can have.

For example, a Cat versus a Chair.  A cat can probably move around under it's own power, make noises, etc.  A chair on the other hand might be moved by a player, sat in, or even turned into firewood or whatever.

So, you'd have a top level class definition for WorldObject of which you would derive an Animal class and maybe an InanimateClass.  The Animal class might have a type enumeration for Dog, Cat or Zebra.  While the InanimateClass might be further subdivided depending on actions that characters may take with them.

All of these objects would be stored in a List and you could test the object types to determine what operations you can take on them.

This way you can keep the attributes of the objects with the object instances themselves and save yourself a LOT of work.

Comment: This is what I was planning on doing.  However with a Pen and a Pencil, why would I need to create an entirely new class?  Because pens and pencils have little to no functionality in my game, all I would change is the name of the object.  This is why I have ObjectDefs.  My question is, where do I define this list?

Comment: Presumably, a "Pen" and "Pencil" wouldn't necessitate a new class, unless their behavior was different from other inanimate objects.  A base inanimate class should probably support being picked up, thrown, set down, etc...

Comment: Right. If it has new behavior, I make a new class with new derived functions and stuff.  I get it.  That was my plan all along.  Where do I define this std::list<WorldObjectDef>?

Comment: @roadkillguy: as a global.  There are still a few reasons that globals are ok, and this is one of them.  Optionally, if you have a top level "game" class as Mooing Duck recommends, then put it there

Comment: I really recommend a top level game class, to prevent the static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah, I'll probably do that.  How exactly does your Game class work?  Does it just contain game variables like what were talking about or does it have other classes?  Would you pass the list of information in a function or the entire Game class iself?

Comment: `int main() {Game game; return game.run(); }`  The game object _is_ the running code.  It needs to be passed to nothing.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I already have a structure for that kind of thing.  I have multiple for Menus, World Generation, and the Game itself.  Where to define it is a pain.  Maybe in my World class?

Comment: I ended up placing it in an essentially global namespace.  I put some other constants in there too, and it all worked out great.